# Validator for current password, new password and confirm new password

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using microsoft Visual Studio 2010,

Basically I have 3 textbox, doing 3 tiers programming.

The textbox are current Password, new Password and confirm Password.

Can I know which validator should I use to validator that:

1) The users has enter current Password so that they can press button to submit.

2) The user have the choice whether they want to enter new password, if they enter new password, the password should be more than 6 character(cannot use special characters such as `!!@#$%^&*())`. If they enter new password, confirm password field need to enter and compare with new password before they can press button to submit

Comment: A `CustomValidator` will give you good flexibility

Comment: not allowing "special characters" in a password raises a big red flag for me.  You aren't actually storing the passwords in plain text are you?

Comment: I tried field and expression validator. Trying to figure out how to use custom validator but then I do not quite understand what is it about

Comment: Just validate the current password is valid, and use the same validated you used to on the original password, then make sure each validator returned true.

Comment: I storing it into Database

Comment: you need `regex` and `compare` validation controls.

Comment: I tried custom validator it is validating at server side. I need to validate at cilent side

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**
Use ASP.NET Membership controls to manage your passwords. Then add a JavaScript function to validate your data.

Passwords are sensitive data. Hackers will always try to steal them, so programmers have found ways to prevent this.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/rainbow-hash-cracking.html

http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/262

If you haven't read these, there are two major points:

**1** - Don't store the actual password that the user enters: store the hash. A hash is a cryptographic function that turns an input string into a different output. This is a one-way transformation: there is no algorithm to take a hash and turn it back into it's input, but the same input will always produce the same output. (The articles describe clever methods that hackers use to try to find the original input, and ways to prevent hackers from doing these clever things). Also, don't use MD5 as your hash mechanism.

**2** - Cryptography and security are very complicated, so often it's better to use someone else's code.

ASP.NET comes with various membership controls that will do the password management and hashing stuff for you. You can learn more about them here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx

Basically, .NET will build your Login/Forgot Password/Change Password/Create User pages for you. You won't need to worry about hashes or Rainbow Tables or anything like them, because Microsoft wrote all of that code for you.

Regarding your question about Client-Size validation, you will need to do some JavaScript. You can call a JavaScript function when the user clicks "Submit" by adding `OnClientClick="return validate();"` to your button. Then you need to create a `validate()` function (the function can be renamed, as long as you change the `OnClientClick` value as well). This function should help:

```
function validate()
{
    if( $("#<%= PasswordControl1.ClientID %>").val() != $("#<%= PasswordControl2.ClientID %>").val())
    {
        alert("Your passwords don't match. Please enter them again.");
        return false;
    }
    if( $("#<%= PasswordControl1.ClientID %>").val().length < 6 )
    {
        alert("Your password is too short. Please use a longer password.");
        return false;
    }
    // use similar function to test for illegal characters in the password, but most sites will let you enter whatever characters you want (# . ! etc...)


    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```